# Site Collection and IIS Site Exist but Site is down

Tags: site-collection, central-administration, site

Problem: Had a user ask me why a specific site we have is down. I checked and the site is giving a "Site Cant Be Reached" error. So I checked in SharePoint administration site to ensure that it was a site collection, it is. It can be located under Application Management/View all site collections. I also opened up the IIS Manager, and I see the site listed under our current sites listing. But again nothing is coming up when we try to navigate there.

Question: How can I have this site respond and open to its URL and not receive the "cant be reached" error. I have restarted the server and that didn't bring the service back up. What things can i check to ensure the site SHOULD be up and how can I get the site running with the things in place i mentioned before.

I know the site worked previously, it seems to have stopped responding recently. Past few days.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not only the URL you try to reach is a site collection, but it's also a dedicated SharePoint Web application (as per your "I see the site listed under our current sites listing in IIS").

So, a lot of things to check here:

1. Is your DNS properly config? What if you try to ping the host name you try to reach from the client machine? Is the IP address returned by *ping* correct?
2. Does the Web site in IIS have the correct IIS binding (i.e. at least the correct host name)?
3. Can you check whether the application pool the Web site belongs to is started (in IIS)?
4. Are Alternate Access Mappings correctly configured for this Web application in SharePoint (see the CA).